# How to connect two different windows forms keeping both open

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed a desktop application containing two forms. The 2ND form opens on click of first form. Now after opening second form I want to move both forms simultaneously on desktop.
and also the location of form should be changed. Means if second form opens on left side and i move both forms to left of screen after reaching extreme left border the second form should open at right side of first form and vice versa.
now I can open the second form on left or right of first form depending on its location.(If first form is at left side the second will open at its right side and vice versa)
How to do this? 
Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: I set the location of 2nd window using first but while moving first window 2nd window remains as it is the location changes after clicking on 1st window. I want to move 2nd window with 1st, keeping both open.

Answer (score 2):

Change the property `StartPosition` to Manual. Then you can set the location of form by using

```
this.Location = new Point(any x coordinate, any y coordinate);
```

You can also set the coordinates using `Left` subproperty.

```
this.Left = 300;
```

and similarly for right.

Comment: Yes I know this property and I am displaying 2nd form using it. But is there any other way so that forms will be connected instead of changing location.Because i have to move both forms simultaneously

Comment: " forms will be connected instead of changing location". By word "connected" what do you exactly mean? Connected in terms of visually connected or connected in terms of coupling of forms?

Comment: visually connected, the 2nd form is flyout opens onclick of 1st and while moving only Main form moves not 2nd one. after moving, on click of Main form 2nd form opens connected to it which I have done setting its location

Comment: sorry its Eid here so i replied late. kindly correct me if i understood you correctly that when you click some button on main form then a new form opens right? because your above and your questions seems to be contradicting.

Comment: yes the form opens on click of 1st form and the they should be connected still i move the first form and again on clicking 1st form the 2nd form hides.

Comment: please see the new answer to your question and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This might be not a direct answer to your question but you can use it according to your needs. This code shows coupling of forms with each other.
Consider for the first form, when you want to show the second form

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
 Form2 frm;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm = new Form2(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//when you click button1 on form1 it shows form2
    {

        this.Hide();
        frm.Show();
    }
```

now for second form

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 frm;
        public Form2(Form1 fr)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            frm = fr;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//when you click button1 on form2 it shows form1
        {
            this.Hide();
            frm.Show();

        }

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Form2 newform = new Form2();
>
> > this.Hide();
> >
> > > newForm.ShowDialog();
> > >
> > > > this.Show();